# ctrl-tab act as alt-tab for tab selection

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

When pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Windows, a small popup shows all running windows/applications, you can select by mouse, or keep pressing until the one you want is highlighted and release.

On the other hand, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is used to switch tabs within certain application or window instance, but usually there is no popup window to show icons of each tabs, since usually we click by mouse to select tabs.

I just wonder if there is an extension for Chrome that can let <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to select tabs in popup windows? Recently I really enjoy full screen experience using Chrome and that allows me easily switch tabs without leaving full screen.

Comment: Welcome to [SU], @shelper! I'm afraid this sounds a lot like you're asking for a software recommendation, which is considered off-topic according to the [FAQ]. You should browse through the [Chrome Extension Gallery](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) to see if you can find what you're looking for.

Comment: I think this question is specific enough so as not to become not constructive (which would be the main reason to close questions asking for software, extensions, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

For windows users, there's the perfect extension for this. It's called [Tab Thumbnails Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-thumbnails-switcher/jpaiaplhepeiilhiegfnknedhjepknng).

It can redefine <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to show a popup list with your open tabs.
It doesn't have restrictions of which tab it can work on. It works everywhere.

Check it out on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HC7_EI8db4

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @CaldeiraG, what do you mean by "essential parts of the answer". I'm not copying the answer from somewhere else. I'm directly answering the question myself. The question is "*an extension for Chrome that can let Ctrl+Tab to select tabs in popup windows*". That's exactly what my answer is about.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple extensions that render a menu of recently used tabs within the webpage you're viewing when you press a shortcut, but the drawback is they can sometimes interfere with keyboard handling and don't work on pages that Chrome doesn't allow extensions to manipulate.

The closest facsimile to the <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> behavior I've seen is offered by [QuicKey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quickey-%E2%80%93-the-quick-tab-s/ldlghkoiihaelfnggonhjnfiabmaficg) (which I wrote). Once the extension is installed in Chrome, you can:

- Press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> but keep holding the <kbd>alt</kbd> key (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> key on macOS).
- Press <kbd>W</kbd> to move down through the list of recently used tabs.
- Press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> to move up.
- Release <kbd>alt</kbd> to switch to the selected tab. ([GIF animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBxt9.gif) of this flow.)

This works in full-screen mode as well. Not as nice as built-in support would be, but I find it pretty handy.

In addition to the most recently used (MRU) tab menu, QuicKey lets you switch tabs by searching for a title or URL. You can also search bookmarks and history and open those into new tabs.